# Building a VM on the ESX hosts own storage

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

Why is it recommended to build a VM on the shared storage and not on the storage of the host itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because then if your cluster has DRS and/or HA enabled then the VM can be vMotioned from host to host or restart on another host in the event of a host failure (or update even). If you use vSAN then the VM can happily live on the local disk as there will be replicas elsewhere.